# requests payload encoding

Tags: python, python-requests

I use requests to pretend firefox and from the fiddler, I saw header is same, but the SystaxView not same

```
payload = {'searchType':'U'}
s.post(url,data=payload)
```

but I got error 500, From the syntax view, I saw in requests it will change to `searchType=U` 
But Real browser will output `searchType='U'`.

I tried `payload = {'searchType':'\'U\''}` it will become`searchType=%27U%27` in Syntax view.

any idea? I only find 1 difference, so I suspect it will trigger 500 error.

```
import requests

s=requests.Session()
s.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0'})
s.get('http://gls.fehd.gov.hk/fehd_lgs/jsp/search/searchMainPage.jsp?lang=zh_TW')
s.headers.update({'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'})
s.headers.update({'Referer': 'http://gls.fehd.gov.hk/fehd_lgs/jsp/search/searchMainPage.jsp?lang=zh_TW', 'HOST':'gls.fehd.gov.hk'})
s.headers.update({'Accept': 'application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01'})
payload={'searchType':'U','deceased_surName':'','deceased_firstName':'','deceased_age':'','deceased_gender':'M','deceased_nationality':'','deathYear':'','deathMonth':'default','deathDay':'default','burialYear':'','burialMonth':'default','burialDay':'default','sectionNo':'','graveNo':''}

url='http://gls.fehd.gov.hk/FEHD_LGS/util/getSearchResult.jsp'

s.post(url,data=payload)
```

Comment: Try `payload = {'searchType': 'U'}` instead

Comment: `{'searchType'='U'}` isn't valid syntax... Are you actually doing what @Andersson suggests above?

Comment: sorry, my typo, i tried  {'searchType': 'U'} and {'searchType' :'\'U\''} but not work, it will change to %27, not sure is encoding related???

Comment: Can you share the error traceback please?

Comment: @cgl server will return 'HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error' if I use python to get

Comment: Actually, i want to get data from this web http://gls.fehd.gov.hk/fehd_lgs/jsp/search/searchMainPage.jsp?lang=en, i use fiddle to see it will call another URL when POST method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value you want to send is `'U'` this might help you send it correctly.

```
payload = {'searchType': "'U'"}
s.post(url,data=payload)
```

Edit:

I don't think you need to make a post request. Try making a get request:

```
url='http://gls.fehd.gov.hk/FEHD_LGS/util/getSearchResult.jsp' 

response = requests.get("%s?%s" % (url, "searchType='U'&deceased_surname=%E6%A5%8A&deceased_firstname=&deceased_age=&deceased_gender='M'&deceased_nationality=&deathYear=&deathMonth=default&deathDay=default&burialYear=&burialMonth=default&burialDay=default&sectionNo=&graveNo=–"))

print(response.content.decode())

select * from cccs_dece_info where SITE_ID in (12,13) and GRAVE_TYPE in ('U') and ( DECEASED_CNAME like '楊%' or upper(DECEASED_ENAME) like '楊 %' or DECEASED_ALIAS = '楊' or DECEASED_ALIAS = '楊')  and ( DECEASED_SEX_CODE in ('M', 'U'))  and ( GRAVE_NO='–' )
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Comment: thx, but also will become %27, actually, maybe not related , just see the difference from fiddler

Comment: Sorry I think I could not follow the question well, encoded value of a single quote is %27

Comment: This one is from Firefox and I use fiddler to capture searchType='U'&deceased_surname=%E6%A5%8A&deceased_firstname=&deceased_age=&deceased_gender='M'&deceased_nationality=&deathYear=&deathMonth=default&deathDay=default&burialYear=&burialMonth=default&burialDay=default&sectionNo=&graveNo=

Comment: Thanks. It works. Not sure why from the packet capture is post method. So I just keep use POST, but do you know why post not work? The last one should be graveNo="

Answer (score 0):

If your server handle post payload in json format, format your payload to json first.

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://someurl.com/"

# format for json payload
def post(url, param):
       payload = json.dumps(param)
       payload = payload.replace(", ", ",")
       payload = payload.replace("{", "{\n\t")
       payload = payload.replace("\",", "\",\n\t")
       payload = payload.replace("}", "\n}")
       return response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload)

payloads = dict(searchType ='U')
response = post(url, payloads)
print(response.response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code, look like there are something wrong with your url/server,.. I checked with Postman look like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8f93.png)

Have you tried another method to do POST payload? (ex:Postman or PHP POST Method)